# How to create custom syncfusion grid-columns without losing the search function provided by syncfusion?

Tags: typescript, angular7, syncfusion

I need to map data receiving from the backend like for example the status of an user which is of type number and map the number to a string.

I could do that with typescript but then I lose the filtering option provided by syncfusion. 
I thought about catching the data before displaying it map them and then display them but I am not really sure how to do that.

In user.component.html

```
<ej-grid id="Grid" #grid [dataSource]="datasource.infos" allowPaging="true" 
    allowFiltering="true">
    <e-columns>
      <e-column field="status" headerText="Status"></e-column>
    </e-columns>
</ej-grid>
```

In user.component.ts

```
  status = {
       0:"None"
       }

  items: object;
     ngOnInit() {
       this.data.getUser().subscribe(data => { 
         this.datasource.infos.push(data) 
          this.items = this.datasource.infos;
        })
      }
```

In datasource.ts

`infos: object[] = []`

How do I map the status receiving from the backend with the number 0 with the string "none" without losing the filtering option? Creating my custom column did not work. I lost the filtering for that custom column..

Thank your for your help.

Comment: What is the backend type? Is this ASP.NET or some other?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have changed the Grid column cell value based on that particular column data source and you want to apply the filter action for that column. For changing the cell value, I suggest to **valueAccessor** Grid property and for the filter action, I suggest to use apply the custom filter for that particular column. You can easily apply the custom filter for that particular column by using **filterbarTemplate** feature of the Grid. Please find the below sample for reference.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/6rckem?file=index.ts

Documentation link:

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/grid/filtering/#filter-bar-template-with-custom-component

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/grid/columns/#valueaccessor

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to display the text as “none” for value 0 in ejGrid. You can achieve your requirement using two ways

1. QueryCellInfo event
2. Foreignkey column.

**QueryCellInfo event:**

queryCellInfo event will be triggered for each and every cell in a row. Using this event you can change the value as none. But it will used only for displaying purpose. In the dataSource value will be 0 for that column.  While filtering also you cannot filter the value using none text.

Refer the  API documentation for your reference.

https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejgrid#events:querycellinfo

**Foreignkey column:**

In ejGrid, we given support for foreignkey column where user can bind dataSource separately to column. Values for the that column will be in form of **text and value pair**. (i.e) one text will be shown in view and its corresponding value will be accessed for all other purposes. So I suggest you to achieve your requirement using foreignkey support.

Refer our UG documentation for your reference

https://help.syncfusion.com/angular/grid/columns#foreign-key-column

Please let us know if you have any concerns.